# Virtualbox share network of host

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

We've set up a docker container on a virtual Ubuntu, running on a real Windows10. the problem now is that going to localhost:4211 on the vm works, but we cannot access it from outside.

We've tried changing the settings of the vm by going through the settings → network → adapter 1 → attached to: bridged adapter

but then at name it says 'not selected' and we cannot save it.

Here's a screenshot
[image]